# Primary Key of Child Table as Foreign Key in Parent Table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have two tables:

**Store**

```
(PK: StoreID)
```

Store is overall parent and

**Product**

```
 Product (PK: ProductID, FK: StoreID)
```

is a child.

I am stuck in a requirement where for an application **Primary Key ProductID** should be foreign key in table **Store** . Not sure if this is gonna work. I have tried this from a custom framework with Oracle backend, but that is not working as expected.

**Note**: I cannot change schema.

Comment: so  what is you question?

Comment: basically, the question is whether this approach is feasible or not in Oracle because when I have attempted this it didn't work (may possible it errored from my side)

Comment: You should show what you actually tried and how it failed so that others can see if it was _...error from your side_ and help you in that case.

Comment: *"I am stuck in a requirement where for an application Primary Key ProductID should be foreign key in table Store."* So each store can have only one product? (It's uncommon for a *requirements* document to identify foreign keys, and to direct where they'll be stored. Are you sure this is a requirement?)

Answer (score 0):

I fail to fully understand your question, but it's possible to have multiple references between two tables. For example:

```
create table store (
  storeid number(6) primary key not null,
  name varchar2(20) not null,
  last_productid number(6) not null -- not yet a FK, but later it is.
);

create table product (
  productid number(6) primary key not null,
  name varchar2(50) not null,
  storeid number(6) not null,
  constraint fk1 foreign key (storeid) references store (storeid)
);

alter table store add
  constraint fk2 foreign key (last_productid) references product (productid);
```

The column `last_productid` you want to add (do you want to?) is a little bit tricky. You have two options:

- It's not nullable. This happens when you want every store to ALWAYS have a last_productid. You'll need to declare it `DEFERRABLE` to be able to insert the store and first product.
- It's nullable. Then some stores will point to a product, and other ones will not. This is the easy case, since you can insert/update the `store` table easily.

Comment: Yes, 'last_productid' I want to add as a foreign key of Store. It won't be null for sure. Need to see how option 1 can be implemented on the framework.